# Storing information about Hadoop job in file

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop and wanted to know how to write to a common output file to store metadata about a recently executed job.

Currently if I am processing files a,b,c and d ; I have a custom counter which adds information about the number of files prcoessed but I wanted to know all the file names which were processed also.

Any comments on the best ways to do it? 
Can Distributed Cache help?

Answer (score 0):

[Context.setStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext.html#setStatus%28java.lang.String%29)

will help?

Use like so:

```
Context.setStatus("Processed "+file);
```